# Capistrano deployment, god start showing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano, god

I have used Rails 4

I am using gem 'god' for restarting sidekiq if server crashes.

But after deploying through capistrano getting error.

```
The server is not available (or you do not have permissions to access it)
```

I have tried with different commands.

```
bundle exec god start
god status
god load 'path_to_config_god'
```

All commands showing the same error.

How can I get it run?

Please give some advice.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried god terminate and then do god start.

Comment: Yes but same error I find in both commands.

Comment: I +1'd because I love the gem's name `god`. It reminds me of God mode in quake - EPIC!

Comment: Is it your sidekiq process is running? Since sidekiq has removed capistrano support.

Comment: @RahulChaudhari .. yes it is running.

Comment: can you provide more details with you cap script and steps ?

Comment: http://roratmindfiresolutions.wordpress.com/2014/05/08/monitoring-jobs-with-sidekiq/